# How to center in the definition context?

Tags: newtheorem

I want to have several short definitions on the same line as the definition number. With that purpose in mind, how may one center A is B in the last definition?

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{Definiton}{Definiton}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{Definiton}
         A is B
 \end{Definiton}

\begin{Definiton}
 \begin{center}
A is B
 \end{center}
\end{Definiton}

\begin{Definiton}
 \begin{center}
     \hfill A is B 
 \end{center}
\end{Definiton}



\begin{Definiton}
 \begin{center}
     \hfill A is B ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
 \end{center}
\end{Definiton}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends importantly on what the centering operation is supposed to span. Do you want to center "A is B" on the *remainder part* of the line (i.e., after subtracting the space taken up by the string "**Definition n.**") or on the *entire* line? Solutions for both cases are given below. Note that the code uses `\hspace*{\fill}` instead of `\hfill`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,showframe}
\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
$|$
\end{center}

\begin{Definition}
\hspace*{\fill}
A is B
\hspace*{\fill}
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}
\hspace*{\fill}
A is B
\hspace*{\fill}\hphantom{\textup{\textbf{Definition \theDefinition.}}}
\end{Definition}

\begin{center}
$|$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, don't advertise `\null` to beginners and use `\hspace*(\fill}`.

Answer (score 5):

If you *really* want to hinder readability, you can either center in the available space (definition 2) or center absolutely (definition 3).

The package `zref` and `\centerref` are only needed if you choose the third way.

Also, `showframe` and `\markcenter` should be removed from the production version.

Personally, I'd not try and push things far away from what they belong to, so I'd stick to the definition 1 style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example

\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}

\newcounter{centerdef}
\newcommand{\centerdef}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \stepcounter{centerdef}%
  \zsaveposx{CENTERDEF\arabic{centerdef}}%
  \makebox[\dimeval{\columnwidth+1in-\zposx{CENTERDEF\arabic{centerdef}}sp}]{#1}%
}


% just for the example
\newcommand{\markcenter}{\par{\centering\vrule height8pt\par}}

\begin{document}

\markcenter

\begin{Definition}
A is B
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}
\hfill A is B\hspace*{\fill}
\end{Definition}

\begin{Definition}
\centerdef{A is B}
\end{Definition}

\markcenter

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the first LaTeX run after adding a `\centerdef` will produce an overfull box, but the next run will be OK.

Comment: I like the advice to "not try and push things far away from what they belong to".